# How do I fix "RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" while using google colab?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, webcam, facial-identification

I am writing the following Python code in Google [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Colaboratory) and get an error:

**Code**:

```
import cv2
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

hog_face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

dlib_facelandmark = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

while True: _,
frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = hog_face_detector(gray)
for face in faces:

    face_landmarks = dlib_facelandmark(gray, face)

    for n in range(0, 16):
        x = face_landmarks.part(n).x
        y = face_landmarks.part(n).y
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 1, (0, 255, 255), 1)


cv2.imshow("Face Landmarks", frame)

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 27:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error**:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 6 hog_face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
> 7
> ----> 8 dlib_facelandmark = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
> 9
> 10 while True:
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

Answer (score 10):

Your notebook is unable to open the file `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`. This may happen because the file isn't uploaded on your notebook, or because the path you specified in `dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")` is wrong.

The following is an edit of your code that automatically downloads the `bzip2` file, extracts it and sets it as your shape predictor. You can use different `.dat` files by changing the link of `!wget`.

**Cell 1:**

```
!wget   http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2 # DOWNLOAD LINK

!bunzip2 /content/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

datFile =  "/content/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
```

**Cell 2:**

```
import cv2 
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

hog_face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

dlib_facelandmark = dlib.shape_predictor(datFile)

while True: _, 
frame = cap.read() 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = hog_face_detector(gray)
for face in faces:

    face_landmarks = dlib_facelandmark(gray, face)

    for n in range(0, 16):
        x = face_landmarks.part(n).x
        y = face_landmarks.part(n).y
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 1, (0, 255, 255), 1)


cv2.imshow("Face Landmarks", frame)

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 27:
    break
cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Moreover, be aware that if you use `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` on a Jupyter notebook to open a camera it won't work, since the code is running on some remote server, and not on you computer. Look at the snippet [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=buJCl90WhNfq) for an example on how to access your local webcam in Colab.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked for a similar problem was downloading Anaconda 3 and installing dlib as guided here: https://learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-windows/

I also changed the project interpreter to Anaconda (I use PyCharm)

Answer (score -2):

```
# add os module 
import os
# then create a variable pwd 
pwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# then put pwd variable before url of the file

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(pwd + '/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
```